# vector-graphics language based on XML

Tags: xml

Dears,
I am learning VML (vector markup language) and PGML (precision graphics markup language),
and I coded a simple example in vml and test it on the internet explorer  6,
it is open successfully, but about pgml code, I still don't know how to add it to my web page, or even how to use pgml file in any web application.
Does any one have idea about this PGML

Comment: Did you post this via time machine from 10 years ago, or was "internet explorer 6" a typo? That is an incredibly out-dated piece of software, which even Microsoft themselves actively encourage people to throw away.

Comment: As for PGML, if you don't know what it's for, why did you start looking at it in the first place? Where did you hear about it? By far the most common "vector-graphics language based on XML" is SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics).

Comment: Dear IMSoP, I am doing  a research about comparing those languages and finally, show how SVG is special and it is recomended.

Comment: OK, then I think this probably isn't the right place to be asking. It sounds like what you really want is to find an expert on PGML you can talk to, or links to some introductory material on where it is used. Neither of those fit well with the format and purpose of this site as described in the [help].

Comment: A quick glance at [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Graphics_Markup_Language) suggests PGML was a proposal that never got beyond an early draft, so it's entirely possible that no software was ever written to render it.